# Explicit Boxing between does not work properly with Expression.Convert?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, boxing

Recently, I came across some troubles about boxing using Expression Trees when I was developing my homemade SQLite ORM. I am still coding again C# 3.5.

To make a long story short, I'm gonna use this simple class definition:

```cs
[Table]
public class Michelle
{
    [Column(true), PrimaryKey]
    public UInt32 A { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public String B { get; set; }
}
```

So this from that POCO class definition I instantiated a new object and my ORM engine converted that object into a record and it's properly inserted. Now the trick is that when I get back the value from SQLite I got an `Int64`.

I thought that my delegate setter was OK because it's an `Action<Object, Object>` but I still got that `InvalidCastException`. Seems that the `Object` (parameter, an `Int64`) is attempted to be cast into a `UInt32`. Unfortunately it does not work. I tried to add some `Expression.Constant` and `Expression.TypeAs` (that one does not really help for value typed objects).

So I am wondering what sort of things are wrong in my setter generation.

Here below is my setter generation method:

```cs
public static Action<Object, Object> GenerateSetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    if (!FactoryFastProperties.CacheSetters.ContainsKey(propertyInfo))
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfoSetter = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod();
        ParameterExpression parameterExpressionInstance = Expression.Parameter(FactoryFastProperties.TypeObject, "Instance");
        ParameterExpression parameterExpressionValue = Expression.Parameter(FactoryFastProperties.TypeObject, "Value");

        UnaryExpression unaryExpressionInstance = Expression.Convert(parameterExpressionInstance, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        UnaryExpression unaryExpressionValue = Expression.Convert(parameterExpressionValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType);

        MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(unaryExpressionInstance, methodInfoSetter, unaryExpressionValue);

        Expression<Action<Object, Object>> expressionActionObjectObject =  Expression.Lambda<Action<Object, Object>>(methodCallExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpressionInstance, parameterExpressionValue });

        FactoryFastProperties.CacheSetters.Add(propertyInfo, expressionActionObjectObject.Compile());
    }

    return FactoryFastProperties.CacheSetters[propertyInfo];
}
```

So basically:

```
// Considering setter as something returned by the generator described above
// So:

// That one works!
setter(instance, 32u);

// This one... hm not really =/
setter(instance, 64);
```

I should probably add another `Expression.Convert` but I do not really know how it would help to make it work. Since there is already one supposed to (attempt to) convert from any `Object` to the property type (here in my example the `UInt32` type).

Any idea to fix it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer, assume the following is defined:

```
object myColValueFromTheDatabase = (object)64L;
```

`Expression.Convert` determines statically how the conversion is to be performed. Just like C# does. If you write `(uint)myColValueFromTheDatabase` this will not succeed at runtime because unboxing just does not work that way. `Expression.Convert` does a simple unboxing attempt as well. That's why it fails.

You would need to do either of the following:

1. `(uint)(long)myColValueFromTheDatabase`
2. `Convert.ToUInt32(myColValueFromTheDatabase)`

In case (1) you need to unbox to the exact-match type first, then change the bits. Case (2) resolves this using some helper methods. Case (1) is faster.

To do this with the expression API, insert another `Expression.Convert`.

---

This should get you started:

```
    public static T LogValue<T>(T val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val.GetType().Name + ": " + val);
        return val;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression myColValueFromTheDatabase = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(1234L), typeof(object));
        myColValueFromTheDatabase = Expression.Call(typeof(Program), "LogValue", new[] { myColValueFromTheDatabase.Type }, myColValueFromTheDatabase); //log
        Expression unboxed = Expression.Convert(myColValueFromTheDatabase, typeof(long));
        Expression converted = Expression.Convert(unboxed, typeof(uint));

        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<uint>>(converted).Compile()();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Comment: `Expression.ConvertChecked` is safer...?

Comment: @DavidHaney what does safer mean for you? It does runtime range checks, but it does not address the issue of this question.

Comment: I tried to add another Expression.Convert as follows:
UnaryExpression unaryExpressionProperty = Expression.Convert (parameterExpressionProperty, parameterExpressionProperty.Type.UnderlyingSystemType);
       unaryExpressionProperty = Expression.Convert (unaryExpressionProperty, typeProperty);

But still get this exception, I can't get really know why. The type of parameterExpression should be an Int64 just like at the runtime and then casting to the type of the property (UInt32), so technically I'm wrappring this way: (UInt32)(Int64)myColValueFromTheDatabase

Anything wrong?

Comment: These expressions are a little confusing to me. I added some code to the answer so that we can talk about something executable. Note the function LogValue which is used to debug runtime values in the expression tree. You can use it to debug unboxing and casts to ensure that the runtime type is what you expect. I suspect that some value has an unexpected type in your program.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking about writing a logger, the thing is that the parameter did not behave the way I expected. Actually I can't really get the Int64 information from the ParamaterExpression, it just remains as an Object. So no matter how many Expression.Convert I used I can't really Unbox the underline Int64 Type boxed.

I decided to move the conversion logic apart of this Expressions. It also better reflects the way I used to set a get properties at compile-time.

It probably brings a huge performance hit by using Convert.ChangeType (even if Reflector shows something quite optimized)

Comment: Yeah, don't use `Convert.ChangeType` if the statically know all the types. Note, that in `Expression.Convert(parameterExpressionValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType)` the runtime value of `parameterExpressionValue` must be exactly of type `propertyInfo.PropertyType` for the unboxing to work. If you need to deal with dynamic types, you can't use a static unbox. Remember, That `Convert` does not do any runtime logic at all. It decides at the point you convert to IL (`Compile`) what to emit.

Comment: For now, I use Convert.ChangeType and it works fine, it brings a certain small bottleneck but I will see later how to make it better. As a said it seems, to me, more consistent to move this conversion / boxing / unboxing thing apart of the Expression code.